# How to get one column from my database into dictionary using Swift3

Tags: ios, swift3

I want to insert the name column from my database into dictionary then sort it and add sections to my tableView. 
I have function that store only the names from the database and return MutableArray and another function that return array of dictionary.
I don't know why but my MutableArray always nil, the only way I'v managed to get the values is when I try to sorted the dictionary and got the return value of type : [String, [String]] instead of [String: [String]]

my code:

```
let sharedInstance = ModelManager()   

class ModelManager: NSObject {

var database: FMDatabase? = nil

class func getInstance() -> ModelManager
{
    if(sharedInstance.database == nil)
    {
        sharedInstance.database = FMDatabase(path: Util.getPath("test3.sqlite"))
    }
    return sharedInstance
}

func getAllCrimesNames() -> NSMutableArray {    // Part1: database into mutableArray
    sharedInstance.database!.open()
    let resultSet: FMResultSet! = sharedInstance.database!.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM CrimeTable", withArgumentsIn: nil)
    let marrCrimesInfo : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    if (resultSet != nil) {
        while resultSet.next() {
            let crimesInfo : NameInfo = NameInfo()
            crimesInfo.Name = resultSet.string(forColumn: "Name")
            marrCrimesInfo.add(crimesInfo)
        }
    }

    sharedInstance.database!.close()
    return marrCrimesInfo
}

}
```

Part 2: get my mutableArray into dictionary and sort it

```
class SectionData {

var marrCrimesNames : NSMutableArray!


func getCrimesNames() {
    marrCrimesNames = NSMutableArray()
    marrCrimesNames = ModelManager.getInstance().getAllCrimesNames()
}


func getSectionsFromData() -> [String: [String]] {

    var sectionDictionary =  [String: [String]]()

    if marrCrimesNames != nil {   // for some reason always nil!

    let crime: NameInfo = marrCrimesNames.object(at: 0) as! NameInfo
    _ = crime.Name
    var firstLetter: [String] = []

    for crime in marrCrimesNames {
        firstLetter.append((crime as AnyObject).Name)
    }

    let characters = Array(Set(firstLetter.flatMap({ $0.characters.first })))

    for character in characters.map({ String($0) }) {
        sectionDictionary[character] = firstLetter.filter({ $0.hasPrefix(character) })
    }

    //var sortedSectionDictionary = Array(sectionDictionary.keys).sorted()   // return [String, [String]] instead of [String: [String]]

    }
    return sectionDictionary
}
```

}

I know it's a lot but I'm missing something simple and I really need help here.
Thank you all...

Comment: You are programming in Swift. Why are you using `NS[Mutable]Array` instead of an actual Swift array?

Comment: I could change it, still doesn't solve the problem

Comment: If you want to know why `marrCrimesNames` is always `nil`, use your debugger and trace the execution of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to sort a dictionary. Dictionaries are unordered.

My guess is that you want your table's data to be represented by a sorted array of sections. Each section could be represented by a struct with two fields, one for the first letter and one for the array of names in that section.

You can convert your `sectionDictionary`, which maps first letters to arrays of names, to a sorted array of section structs using code like this:

```
struct CrimeNameSection {
    let firstLetter: String
    let names: [String]
}

func getSectionsFromData() -> [CrimeNameSection] {
    // make sure marrCrimesNames is non-nil
    guard marrCrimesNames != nil else {
        return []
    }

    // add each name to dictionary mapping first letters to name arrays
    var sectionDictionary =  [String : [String]]()
    for crime in marrCrimesNames {
        let crime = crime as! NameInfo
        let firstChar = String(crime.Name[crime.Name.startIndex])
        if var names = sectionDictionary[firstChar] {
            names.append(crime.Name)
            sectionDictionary[firstChar] = names
        } else {
            sectionDictionary[firstChar] = [crime.Name]
        }
    }

    // convert sectionDictionary to sorted array of CrimeNameSections
    let sections = sectionDictionary.map { (key, value) in
        return CrimeNameSection(firstLetter: key, names: value)
    }
    let sortedSections = sections.sorted { $0.firstLetter < $1.firstLetter }

    return sortedSections
}
```

Comment: I have 60 values it's a lot of work to map all the data can't it be done from the data without maping every value manually?

Comment: No, you wouldn't want to map the data manually, that was just for trying the code in a playground. I've removed those lines, and added the rest of `getSectionsFromData()`. I hope that is clearer. The other comments I would make would be to consider renaming the `Name` field in `NameInfo` to `name` (Swift member names usually start with a lowercase letter), and to consider using a Swift array rather than `NSMutableArray` for `marrCrimesNames`.

Comment: The NSMutableArray holds all the database, my database contains three columns: name, detail, time. I can convert the mutableArray into swift array if you think it's better that way